Basic auth with socat for plain http traffic
My question is as follows: I need to organize some sort of authorization between http server and client, provided I have no access to their configuration. That needs to be as simple as possible because it happens inside uC environment, so memory is precious.
I decided to place a nginx rev proxy in front of http server (as I can do this on a separate PC) with BASIC authorization required for a location I need, but unfortunately I can't figure out how to make it with a client that is closed source and cannot perform it out of box.
I was thinking about some sort of tunnel  with socat utility without any encryption of any sort. If only I could pipe together socat for a tunnel and curl utility for Basic authorization - but I don't know how to make it. I feel that socat must provide data for curl , but how to configure it all together? Or is it completely wrong path?
Thank you.

Building your own proxy out of curl and socat is definitely the wrong approach.
However beyond that, it is not clear from your question what you are trying to achieve.
Do you mean that

the origin server already enforces basic auth and you want to make this transparent?

the origin server does NOT require any authentication but you want to add this requirement? (here be dragons: you need additional measures to prevent direct access, bypassing anything you put in place)

Something else?


For the first 2 scenarios above, nginx would be my go to tool here. The second of these simply requires a proxy_set_header Authorization Basic..... The former, something like:
          auth_basic           "Restricted";
          auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/userauth;

There several tools available for creating the userauth file - the simplest is probably to use the htpasswd executable from the apache-utils package.
If this does not work, then post details of the configuration files and what actually happenned )http headers, log file entries) as a new question.

What I try to do is simple: I want to secure the systemd-journal-* interchange but without TLS overhead as it takes too much computational power from uC. I need just authorization without encryption so I decided to create something like a http-with-basic-auth tunnel.

I infer from "tunnel" you mean the first scenario I described above, but I did ask an explicit question and did not get an explicit answer. I don't know what you mean by "systemd-journal-* interchange" nor why you using systemd and systemd journal on a host contrained for memory, but this is starting to sound like the XY problem.
